# How to improve our 3-year-old's sleep cycle without skipping long afternoon nap?

Tags: pre-schooler, bedtime, sleep-training, daycare

My 3-ear-old goes to daycare where they have the policy to not wake up the sleeping kids. Therefore she ends up taking 3 hours nap from 12-3. When she comes home around 6 pm, she would be all fresh and active and won't sleep till 12-1 am, even if I take her to bed early and switch off the lights.

I have tried to request daycare teachers several times to wake her up early, but they simply say they cannot do that.

What kind of activities should I try to make her tired and sleep in time? As it's quite cold, we cannot do many outdoors activities. At home, we try to jump/dance and play with bubbles. Any suggestions on how to improve the sleep cycle?

Comment: Is changing daycare an option? 3 hours is a long nap.

Comment: @anongoodnurse it is a very long nap, many of my friends kids had dropped that nap completely by 3 years old

Comment: have you asked them to skip the nap completely?

Comment: What is the schedule and cycle like when the child isn't at daycare?

Comment: then its pretty good. she does not take afternoon nap and goes ro bed in time

Answer (score 3):

If my kids would sleep from 12 to 3, they would have a similar problem. Your kids seem not to need so much sleep. Some need more, some less.

Skipping the nap or change daycare is an option. It is your kid and also your sleep.

I know changing daycare is not an easy step. Your kid may have friends there and trust to the employees. Maybe showing the option of changing daycare to the employees there opens theirs eyes.

Maybe it is a way to not go to sleep at 12 but at 1 or so?`In our daycare they wake the kids at 3, no matter when they went to sleep.